# Golang concurrency deadlock

Tags: go, concurrency, deadlock

Can anyone help me determine why I get deadlock errors at the end of this Go code I'm writing?  The program actually runs properly but I get a deadlock errors.  I'm new to writing concurrent code so any help is greatly appreciated.  I have omitted some lines that I know aren't the problem just to make it quicker to read.

```
func MoveWorksheets(worksheetList []string) {

var wg sync.WaitGroup

for _, worksheet := range worksheetList {

    wg.Add(1)

    go MoveFile(src, dst, wg)

    }

    wg.Wait()
}

func MoveFile(src, dst string, wg sync.WaitGroup) (err error) {

    defer wg.Done()

    sfi, err := os.Stat(src)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    if !sfi.Mode().IsRegular() {
        // cannot copy non-regular files (e.g., directories,
        // symlinks, devices, etc.)
        return fmt.Errorf("CopyFile: non-regular source file %s (%q)", sfi.Name(), sfi.Mode().String())
    }
    dfi, err := os.Stat(dst)
    if err != nil {
        if !os.IsNotExist(err) {
            return
        }
    } else {
        if !(dfi.Mode().IsRegular()) {
            return fmt.Errorf("CopyFile: non-regular destination file %s (%q)", dfi.Name(), dfi.Mode().String())
        }
        if os.SameFile(sfi, dfi) {
            return
        }
    }
    /*if err = os.Link(src, dst); err == nil {
        return
    }*/
    err = MoveFileContents(src, dst)
    return
}

func MoveFileContents(src, dst string) (err error) {

    merr := os.Rename(src, dst)

    if merr != nil {
        log.Fatal(merr)
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: The stack trace should show you where you're blocking. What is the output?

Comment: fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc08200274c)
        C:/Go/src/runtime/sema.go:47 +0x2d
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc082002740)
        C:/Go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:127 +0xbb
main.MoveWorksheets(0xc08200a400, 0x14, 0x20)
        C:/code/src/github.com/deisun/adminsorter/adminsorterc.go:162 +0x27
main.Run()
        C:/code/src/github.com/deisun/adminsorter/adminsorterc.go:40 +0xa6
main.main()
        C:/code/src/github.com/deisun/adminsorter/adminsorterc.go:26 +0x46

Comment: BTW, `go vet` catches this error.

Answer (score 1):

`MoveFile` is getting a copy of `wg`, so you're calling `Wait()` and `Done()` on different `WaitGroup`s. Try passing it as a pointer.

Comment: Wow that was it...thank you so much!   I'm an idiot, can't believe I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing reference of the `wg` variable, in your code `MoveFile` function is getting its own copy of WaitGroup. That's why it is creating a deadlock.

```
   func MoveWorksheets(worksheetList []string) {

        var wg sync.WaitGroup

        for _, worksheet := range worksheetList {

          wg.Add(1)

          go MoveFile(src, dst, &wg)

        }

        wg.Wait()
    }

    func MoveFile(src, dst string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) (err error) {

        defer wg.Done()

        sfi, err := os.Stat(src)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        if !sfi.Mode().IsRegular() {
            // cannot copy non-regular files (e.g., directories,
            // symlinks, devices, etc.)
            return fmt.Errorf("CopyFile: non-regular source file %s (%q)", sfi.Name(), sfi.Mode().String())
        }
        dfi, err := os.Stat(dst)
        if err != nil {
            if !os.IsNotExist(err) {
                return
            }
        } else {
            if !(dfi.Mode().IsRegular()) {
                return fmt.Errorf("CopyFile: non-regular destination file %s (%q)", dfi.Name(), dfi.Mode().String())
            }
            if os.SameFile(sfi, dfi) {
                return
            }
        }
        /*if err = os.Link(src, dst); err == nil {
            return
        }*/
        err = MoveFileContents(src, dst)
        return
    }

    func MoveFileContents(src, dst string) (err error) {

        merr := os.Rename(src, dst)

        if merr != nil {
            log.Fatal(merr)
        }

        return
    }
```